# How to count records for the particular repeated records?

Tags: sql

I have a table name is Pattern

```
S.No      type      Id_Section
    1          A        IPS
    2          A        IPS
    3          A        IPS
    4          A        IPS
    1          B        IPS
    2          B        IPS
    3          B        IPS
    1          C        IPS
    2          C        IPS
    1          D        IPS
    2          D        IPS
```

I want a query to count records except where type = "c" records  ...I tried with and examples..But i am getting whole records count..Please any one help me..

Comment: Can you please show us what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM pattern
WHERE type <> 'C'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Pattern WHERE type != 'C'
```

Did I understand you right?